# Ansible - Deploy to same host with using mutiple values for same variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

Ansible version : 2.4.2.0

I'm using a directory as my inventory which has 2 files - a , b

**File a**

`[frontend]
hostname001
[frontend:vars]
envt=frontend`

**File b**

`[backend]
 hostname001
[backend:vars]
envt=backend`

The value of variable is overriden and only backend persists.

Playbook sample

`- name: Sample play
  hosts: '{{ group }}'
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: "Do a demo"
      debug: 
        msg: 'The envt is {{envt}}'`

When i try to deploy frontend by passing group=frontend as extravar, output is as follows

**ok: [hostname001] => {
    "msg": "The envt is backend"
}**

How can i make sure the right variable is picked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that regardless of how you set the `group` variable, your host `hostname001` is still a member of both groups. You're going to need to approach this using a different method.

One option would be to simply move the variable out of your inventory and have a couple of separate variable files that you use with the `-e` option. E.g., you might call `ansible-playbook` like this:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e @config1.yml
```

Or:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e @config2.yml
```

Alternately, maybe you could set the variable per-play instead of per-group.

As a final option, you could given the target host a different name in each group.  E.g., something like:

```
[backend]
hostname001-backend ansible_host=hostname001

[backend:vars]
envt=backend

[frontend]
hostname001-frontend ansible_host=hostname001

[frontend:vars]
envt=frontend
```

Using that inventory, we see:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e group=frontend

PLAY [Sample play] ***************************************************************************

TASK [Do a demo] *****************************************************************************
ok: [hostname001-frontend] => {
    "msg": "The envt is frontend"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
hostname001-frontend       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e group=backend

PLAY [Sample play] ***************************************************************************

TASK [Do a demo] *****************************************************************************
ok: [hostname001-backend] => {
    "msg": "The envt is backend"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
hostname001-backend        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thankyou @larsks The last solution seems to be good for our requirement.